# Fetch and read email id after twitter login

Tags: android

I am writing an application that exists user details after login in twitter using fabric. I've a problem states an authenticate fail which doesn't return email  'com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Authorize failed.' and here is the code

[image]

Comment: try this one http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

There are two way to do this

1. if you are using fabric then you need to ask for permission in twitter developer application console. Twitter will approve your request for accessing email in your app. https://apps.twitter.com/
2. second way to do this by using twitter 4j library(method is depreciated I am not sure but you can try to use this for retrieving email) http://twitter4j.org/en/